# Why Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not considered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lumen

Although I am passing header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the request like this:

```
$http({     method: 'GET',
            url:$APIs_server + "api/get-all-notifications",
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                'Authorization': JWT_token
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            //console.log("response.data: ", response.data);
            if (response.data != undefined)
                $scope.populate_notifications(response.data);

        });
```

I got an error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, here is the full error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:9902/api/get-all-notifications. Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Please advice if someone can explain?

Comment: Because it's not a client side issue

Comment: Do I have to explicitly allow all origins  on the server? , I am not doing any thing special

Comment: Yes. It would be completely useless as a security measure if the client-side code could just decide whether to allow cross-origin requests or not.

Comment: @simo Your server is on different port => Not the same origin as the client

Comment: You can specify your allowed origin from the server so that your access is not open to every client but yours.

Comment: I've implemented a middleware to accept origins from any website for testing but it seems that it's not working

Comment: @Aron do server and client have to be on same port?

Comment: [You betcha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) - _Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, __port (if one is specified)__, and host are the same for both pages_